# React get total amount items in cart

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying get the total items in cart. The problem is though that it only gets the total amount of items that are *unique* items in the cart. If an item is duplicated e.g. has 2 items of the same it does not add to **Total Items**

Here is a CodeSandBox example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-cart-system-tfg1e

I have tried adding an useEffect in `_app.js` something like:

```
const total = items.cart.reduce((amount, item) => { return amount + item.quantity}, 0)
```

But I can't seem to get it to work.

[image]

Any help here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are displaying `cart.items.length` as the "Total Items" but that's just the number of individual items without taking the `quantity` into account. Instead you can use this:

```js
<span>{cart.items.reduce((accum,item) => accum + item.quantity, 0)}</span>
```

The `reduce` function will run through the array of `items` and total up all of the `quantity` values. See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

This is just a short way to do this:

```js
let totalItems = 0;
for (const item of cart.items) {
  totalItems += item.quantity;
}
console.log("Total Items: " + totalItems);
```

Comment: Awesome, that is an good explanation and solution. Thank you!
This means it is without the `context` though that is happening in `_app.js` ?
Since I was trying to add it in `_app.js`

Comment: @Mark Not sure what that means; the `cart` comes from the context.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am starting to think, I might've been looking at it the wrong way.
My idea was I am adding it in `EMPTY_CART` e.g. as `totalitems: 0` and build out the function for it in `_app.js`. And you are right the cart already comes from the context!

Comment: @Mark *Where* the work is done is up to you; in the end it just depends on what the nature of the component is, e.g., is `Cart` isn't going to be used in any other way, it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @DaveNewton I see. I might use `Cart` in the checkout page as well though. But that would make less sense and is better to have a different component for it, now that I am thinking of it.

Comment: @Mark But presumably with the same data, so it wouldn’t matter. If the *layout* is quite different a separate component might make sense. If there are multiple components with the same data it might make sense to do all calculations outside of the views—or it may not be worth the work.